# Resize text based on image size

Tags: html, css

I have an image and a block of text below of it. I'm trying to make max-width of text width of image. (size of image is not defined and size of parent div is not defined too)

```
<div>
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b8/NYers_celebrate_historic_vote_for_gay_marriage.webm/300px--NYers_celebrate_historic_vote_for_gay_marriage.webm.jpg"/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam non risus dolor, a euismod leo. Phasellus viverra aliquet felis eget porttitor. Aenean sollicitudin, nulla id ultrices ullamcorper, sem lectus sagittis metus, ut sodales dui nunc id sem. Vestibulum nisl justo, aliquet id luctus eu, tincidunt sit amet diam. Suspendisse at nulla nisl. Duis sed sapien odio, eget commodo metus. Fusce ultricies lectus sit amet massa tristique eu ultricies elit accumsan. Donec mi mi, elementum sit amet faucibus sed, pellentesque sed neque. Pellentesque ut tincidunt dui. Nullam in urna vitae arcu lobortis porta sit amet a sapien. Maecenas at ultricies erat. Maecenas diam arcu, condimentum eu gravida quis, aliquam at nunc. Duis at fermentum orci. Donec porta feugiat purus faucibus euismod. In pretium auctor nulla, blandit dapibus ante auctor at.</p>
</div>
```

I draw a quick mockup for better understanding - [image]

Codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kJLrF

Is there any way to implement this? (such markup is not required, more elements can be added if required)

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap them in another `div` element, set its max-width property, and then define a 100% width for the image as follows:

```
div {
    max-width: 500px;
}

div img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Please see this jsFiddle demo > http://jsfiddle.net/Vt9CL/

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I don't know width of image (max-width).

Answer (score 1):

if you insist on the structure you've built than JS is the only option.

```
$(init);

function init()
{
  var w = $("img").innerWidth();
  $('p').css({"width": w});
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ikunix/1/

Wrapping image and paragraph text in another container would be better though.

Answer (score 1):

I've played around a bit and I managed to do it with `html` and `css`:
html:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff&text=image" />
   <p>Lorem ipsum [...]</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: -moz-min-content;
   width: -webkit-min-content;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BvrLe/1/)**

The problem is that it works only in firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using this little script:

```
$('p').css('width',$('img').width() + 'px');
```

It is taking the `width` of the `img` and it is applying it to the `width` of `p`.
Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeaxL/)

Answer (score 0):

Mhhhhm, I have no idea if it's possible to do this via css. If you want to get this done without javascript, the only thing which I know is something like this:
http://goo.gl/U3pBE